# imagebutton becomes very large when I choose my avatar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, layout

I have an imagebutton that is fixed to the top right of the navigation menu and when you click on it, you could select an image from your android library and make it as your avatar.

However, once you select your picture, the imagebutton instead becomes very large.

Here is how the button is initally: [Before Choosing avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJLDW.png)

here is how the button is after choosing the avatar: [After choosing avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ3iv.png)

I inserted this piece of code inside the onCreate() method in NavDrawerActivity class

```
imgButton = (ImageButton) navigationHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_UPLOAD_REQUEST);
    }
});

RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), getThumbnail("desiredFilename.png"));
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
imgButton.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
```

Here is my XML:

```
<ImageButton
   android:layout_gravity="right"
   android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/round_button"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into XML to set fixed size:

```
android:maxWidth="42dp"  
android:maxHeight="42dp"
```

42dp is just example, set whatever you want

Comment: I tried with 5 and with 20, but it's the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you've given us to work with, the image size of the avatar is much larger than the original icon. If you want it to be the exact same size as the icon, you could either downscale the image, or change the size of the `ImageButton` from wrap_content to a fixed value. :)

Change this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

To this:

```
android:layout_width="THE WIDTH OF THE ICON"  
android:layout_height="THE HEIGHT OF THE ICON"
```

**EDIT:**
Bit of an abstract thought, but may as well try it.

Change this:

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
```

To this:

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
```

Comment: I never had maxWidth and maxHeight. Do you mean layout_width?

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad.

Comment: I get this now... weird. Not sure what's the problem but thank you for trying... https://imgur.com/a/OKJyB

Comment: That's odd. Please refer to my edit for further steps.

Comment: no luck, just turns the circle into a square instead.

Comment: Is the image just white? If so, try changing it to something that's easier to spot (i.e giving it a RED color) Then we might be able to see if that large white square in the previous image you showed me is the actual image, or if it's just a random object.

Comment: No it's a real image with no white spots..that exact code works on another app but on that app it doesnt for some reason

Comment: Strange. If the code works on another app, could you copy all of the files over into a new project? Or are other things in your current project causing the problem?

Comment: ok got it to work! had some stupid setcolor code that was there for no reason, had to remove it..but now I have a xml problem

Comment: That's great to hear! Could you elaborate on the XML issue?

Comment: I am having this problem https://imgur.com/a/7PWGm .....do you know how to make the lsit stick on top?

Comment: Try: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` or `android:layout_alignTop`

Comment: Are any of the colours you use white?